Two-dimensional integral over data
I am trying to calculate the integral of the data. Following this post, I know what to do with a one-dimensional list. But, let's consider a simple function, just to show you, what I want to do.
f[x_, y_]:= x y;

Now, I create a two-dimensional table
L = Table[f[x,y], {x, 0, 5}, {y,0, 5}];

Now on this data, I would like to do the following operation
Integrate[f[x,y,], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]

For one dimension, I would use the Simpson rule from the mentioned post, but is it possible to extend it to calculate the following integral?

Integrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}](*625/4*)

integration weights
g = Table[1, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}];
g[[All, 1]] = g[[1, All ]] = g[[All, 6]] = g[[6, All ]] = 1/2;
g[[1, 1]] = g[[1, 6]] = g[[6, 1]] = g[[6, 6]] = 1/4;


numerical integration
Flatten[g L] // Total (* 625/4 *)


Thank you very much, can you explain, why you take such weights?

@blahblah Have a look at the grid: Neighborhood of inner points is one, boundary points (except corners) is 1/2 and corners is 1/4. Sum of all weights should be 25

Ok, I understand, but why the sum should be 25 if the array is 6x6?

That's the size of the area 5*5

I wonder if this should be another question, but I will ask it here. What about if I want to specify more points in my list? Due to this fact, I am creating a bigger list of weights.
f[x_, y_] := x y;
L = Table[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5, 0.1}, {y, 0, 5, 0.1}];
g = Table[1, {x, 0, 5, 0.1}, {y, 0, 5, 0.1}];
g[[All, 1]] = g[[1, All]] = g[[All, -1]] = g[[-1, All]] = 1/2;
g[[1, 1]] = g[[1, -1]] = g[[-1, 1]] = g[[-1, -1]] = 1/4;
Flatten[g L] // Total 
The result is 15 625, not. 625/4.

Check the neighbourhood of your new gridpoints: innerpoints  .1^2,boundary points .1^2/2, corner points .1^2/4

Thank you. So, I think my workaround is also correct. Could you confirm, if I am correct? In the above expression (from comment), I declared dx = 0.1 and dy=0.1. Next, instead of 0.1, I put dx and dy in the right places. Thus, the grid may stay as it is, but the main change goes in the last command, i.e., Flatten[g L] dx dy// Total. It returns the same result, independently on dx and dy, that is why I think it's correct. But, I'd appreciate if you could confirm.

Yes , seems to be correct!

Thank you very much for your huge help. Does this method have any name?
